# How to know which `Activity` is in top of stack after opening a `Activity` from notification?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

I have `ActivityA` and I open `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` and I put the app on the background(by pressing home button). Then I triggered a notification, on tap of notification I opened `ActivityA` then it checks a condition(condition inside `ActivityA`) and opens `ActivityC`.

```
ActivityA ---->ActvityB// after this operation put app in history by pressing home button

//from Notification tap open ActivityA

          (check some condition)
ActivityA -----------------------> ActivityC
```

So, My question is How to Know after opening the app(Which is in History) from notification that which Activity is in Top of the stack before?

**Note:-** I also tried `isTaskRoot()` not work for me. Don't post outdated Answers

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Why do you need to know this? Please explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: When I open an app activity through notification(even app in the background). so, on that activity how can I know which Activity is in top of the stack before

Comment: You just repeated your question. You didn't say why you need this information and you didn't explain the problem you are trying to solve. I don't think you need this information and I think your problem can be solved in another way, but I can't know unless you explain exactly what problem you are trying to solve. Sorry, I can't help with the information available.

Comment: When I open activityA from notification and then I visited activityC, if I have an activityB in history before opening activityA from notification then when I backpress from activityC, I want to return to ActivityB

Comment: Post your manifest and the code you use to create the `Intent` and `PendingIntent` for your `Notification` please.

Comment: `ActivityA` is launcher activity, Other are normal in manifest

Comment: Please copy/paste the content of your manifest into the question and copy/paste the code you use to create the `Intent` and `PendingIntent` for the `Notification` into the question. You can edit your question and then add the information I've asked for.